# How to draw an equilateral triangle inscribed in another triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles, computational-geometry

Given a triangle $\Delta$ABC, how to draw any inscribed equilateral triangle whose vertices lie on different sides of $\Delta$ABC?

Comment: Do you mean with ruler and compass ?

Comment: It can be ruler or compass. Or any mathematical or computational way. I just need to code it.

Comment: See animation (https://www.geogebra.org/m/ey3aYYkK)

Comment: I am not a downvoter, but if somebody doxnvotes, there is a reason : you haven't indicated any work done on the subject : where are you blocked, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(See figure and Matlab program below). We are going to show how to capture the issue in all its generality, and thus build a program giving as many inscribed equilateral triangles $UVW$ as desired, the key observation being an affine relationship between the evolution speeds of vertices $U$ and $V$ (and $W$).

One can assume WLOG, using an adequate translation, that $A$ has coordinates $\binom{0}{0}$. Let us name $\binom{a}{b}$ and $\binom{c}{d}$ the resp. coord. of $B$ and $C$. In the example given below, $B$ is in the 3rd quadrant and $C$ in the 4th quadrant, but this is unimportant as long as the names of the vertices $A,B,C$ are chosen such that triangle $ABC$ is positively oriented.

[image]

Consider an inscribed equilateral triangle $UVW$. Let $s$ and $t$ be defined by :

$$\vec{AU}=s \vec{AB} \ \ \ \ \& \ \ \ \ \vec{AV}=t \vec{AC} \ \ \ \ \text{with} \ 0 \leq s,t \leq 1.$$

Let $\binom{x}{y}$ be the coordinates of $W$.

It is not difficult to see that $UVW$ is an equilateral triangle if and only if:

$$\tag{1}\vec{AW}=\underbrace{\tfrac12(\vec{AU}+\vec{AV})}_{\text{midpoint} \ I \text{of} \ UV}+\underbrace{\tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}Rot_{-\tfrac{\pi}{2}}(\vec{UV})}_{\text{altitude} \ \vec{IW}} \ \iff \ \begin{cases}x=\tfrac12(as + ct + \sqrt{3}(dt-bs))\\ y=\tfrac12(bs + dt + \sqrt{3}(as - ct))\end{cases}$$

Now we must constrain $A,B,W$ to be aligned. This will be done in this classical way (see formula (2) in (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Collinear.html)).

$$\tag{2}\begin{vmatrix}a&c&x\\b&d&y\\1&1&1\end{vmatrix}=0.$$

By plugging expressions (1) in (2), one gets a formula that allows $t$ to be expressed as an *affine function* $\alpha s + \beta$ of $s$ (I don't reproduce this formula : it is expressed in the program). This dependency of $t$ on $s$ explains that the loop in the program is controlled by values of $s$ as we can see:

> ```
> clear all,close all;hold on;axis equal
> xA=0;yA=0;% assumed
> a=-1;b=-3; % B's coord.
> c=5;d=-4; % C's coord.
> %a=-rand;b=-rand;c=rand;d=-rand;
> Tr=[0,a,c,0;
>     0,b,d,0];
> plot(Tr(1,:),Tr(2,:),'b');
> r=sqrt(3);
> for s=0:0.05:1
>    N = s*((b+a*r)*(a-c)+(b*r-a)*(b-d))+2*(c*b-a*d);
>    D = (c+d*r)*(b-d) + (c*r-d)*(a-c) ;
>    t = N/D;
>    x=(a*s + c*t - b*r*s + d*r*t)/2;
>    y=(b*s + d*t + a*r*s - c*r*t)/2;
>    W=[x;y];
>    U=s*[a;b];V=t*[c;d];
>    Tequ=[U,V,W,U];
>    if t>0 && t<1 && inpolygon(W(1),W(2),Tr(1,:),Tr(2,:))
>       plot(Tequ(1,:),Tequ(2,:),'color',rand(1,3))
>    end;
> end;
> ```

*Remark:* one can establish that if $U$ has a rectilinear motion on $AB$, then the center of triangle $UVW$ (little red circles on the figure) undergoes as well a rectilinear uniform motion.

Comment: So nice! (+1) $\phantom{}$

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to draw a bisector $AD$ of $\angle CAB$,
$D\in BC$, 
find the intersection of the sides $AC$ and $AB$
with the line $AD$, rotated $\pm30^\circ$ around $D$:

[image]

**Edit**

\begin{align} 
D&=\frac{b\cdot B+c\cdot C}{b+c}
,\\
|AF|=|AE|&=\frac{|AD|}{2\,\sin(30^\circ+\tfrac\alpha2)}
.
\end{align}

Comment: You seem to need a bissector that is as well an altitude : this would mean that  initial triangle ABC is isoceles...

Comment: @Jean Marie: No, it just the illustration was misleading, see updated picture.

Comment: You are right. Besides, for this to be possible, the angle of BC with a certain reference, for example with horizontal direction should be in a certain range : Imagine BC almost horizontal, you couldn't insert a 30° angle...

Comment: @ Jean Marie: yes, but at least one of the three angles (the maximal) will do.

Comment: You are right, once more.

Comment: This is very easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Construction**

1. Use [Morley's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morley%27s_trisector_theorem) to construct an equilateral triangle $\triangle XYZ$ that lies strictly inside $\triangle ABC$.
2. Through the vertices of $\triangle XYZ$, draw three lines parallel to the sides of your original $\triangle ABC$. These lines form a new triangle $\triangle A'B'C'$ that is similar to $\triangle ABC$ and lies strictly inside it. (Thus the equilateral triangle $\triangle XYZ$ is now inscribed in the newly constructed $\triangle A'B'C'$.)
3. Enlarge the figure so that $\triangle A'B'C'$ becomes the size of $\triangle ABC$. The enlarged image of $\triangle XYZ$ is the sought-for inscribed triangle.

Comment: Interesting idea. But not very easy to code.

Comment: Note: there are in fact multiple solutions. The above construction gives just one of many possible inscribed equilateral triangles.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2103767/how-big-is-the-equilateral-triangle-inscribed-in-a-triangle?noredirect=1&lq=1) one way to draw is described in the first comment. But it was too brief to understand, though it seems easy. If anyone can put some light on that, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $A=(0,0)$, $B=(b,0)$, $C=(c,h)$ with $b>0$, $0<c<b$, and $h>0$. We shall construct an equilateral triangle with one side horizontal as follows: Draw a horizontal line $y=h'$, where $h'$ is determined by the condition
$$h'={\sqrt{3}\over2}\>{h-h'\over h}\>b\ .\tag{1}$$
This line intersects the two legs of the triangle in two points $P$ and $Q$. Let $M=(m, h')$ be the midpoint of $PQ$. Then $P$, $Q$, and $R:=(m,0)$ form an equilateral triangle.

The condition $(1)$ ensures that $h'={\sqrt{3}\over2}\>|PQ|$. Solving for $h'$ one obtains
$$h'={h\, b\over{2\over\sqrt{3}}h+b}\ .$$

Comment: The condition $0<c<b$ means that $\triangle ABC$ is an acute triangle.

Comment: @Alex: No. It just means that in case of an obtuse triangle the obtuse angle is at $C$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.