# Solving systems of equations by means of geometric construction

Tags: systems-of-equations, euclidean-geometry

This is a follow up to this question:
[Constructing an equilateral triangle of a given side length inscribed in a given triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3614940/constructing-an-equilateral-triangle-of-a-given-side-length-inscribed-in-a-given?noredirect=1)

My attempts to solve the problem were initially focusing on algebraic/trigonometric. Two approaches led to two sets of equations:

Set 1 - unknowns $m, x_0, x_1$:

$(1+m^2)(x_0+x_1)^2=a^2$

$(x_0-a_0)^2(mx_0-b_0)^2=r_0^2$

$(x_1-a_1)^2(mx_1-b_1)^2=r_1^2$

Set 2 - unknown $x, y, z:

$y^2+(c-z)^2-2y(c-z)cos\alpha=s^2$

$x^2+(b-y)^2-2x(b-y)cos\gamma=s^2$

$z^2+(a-x)^2-2z(a-x)cos\beta=s^2$

I could not find a solution to these to sets of equation.

I successfully solved the original problem by mean of compass and a ruler.

As result two questions raised (at least for me):

1. Is there a NICE solution to any set of these equations?
2. Given the solution by construction, provides a solution to these two sets of equation. Is this a known practice to solve sets of equations? Any example in  the literature?

Will be happy to clarify any issues...

Comment: The answer to your second question is a very definite yes. People solved equations by construction long before they solved them algebraicly. Examples are found in Euclid's Elements and many other early Greek writings. However it can be rather hard to recognize because the *equations* being solved are also stated geometrically, and not in a manner you and I would think of as "equations".

Comment: @Paul if the answer to my first question is YES than there is no advantage to CONSTRUCTIOIN solutions. To your example - are the equations solved by the Greek not solvable in direct analytical way? AS example - if we could have a construction that provide solution to any polynomial with power of 5 than I see an advantage to construction. Make sense?

Comment: I said "second question" not "first". And every question solvable by construction is also solvable analytically. Each constructed point is the solution to a system of equations of the form $(x-x_i)^2 + (y-y_i)^2 = r^2$ or $A(x-x_i) + B(y - y_i)=C$, where the $(x_i, y_i)$ are previously constructed points. All such systems are analyically solvable, so any construction solution can be converted to an analytic solution. As to "advantage" - there are other advantages than just "solves a problem not solvable otherwise".

Comment: Paul, I fully understood your comment. I wonder, based on your second comment, what is the analytical solution to the second set? You could make it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: My comment is that a construction solution can be converted into an analytic solution. (1) I don't have your construction solution to convert (2) I'm pretty sure that your cunstruction solution did not start with the equivalent of those three equations. Instead it probably started with the three vertices and the length. Those equations are ones you derived, and I have no desire to back them out to the true starting place.

Comment: I agree with you that the construction can support the analytical solution, and I know how to do it. I am wondering if there are problems that are solvable (to the best of current knowledge) by construction only. With this respect I am wondering if the two systems of equation are such example. In any case, thanks for your insight.