# Three lines are given. Find three points on these lines, one point on each line, that are vertices of an equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry

> Three lines are given. Find three points on these lines, one point on each line, that are vertices of an equilateral triangle

Well if I consider a point on one line my goal would be to construct the other two points. If the lines are intersecting all at one point perpendicular to each other. Could I then use a circle to construct the other points? I'm a little unsure how to visualize this problem. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Cosider cases. One case is all lines intersect at a point. Second case all lines are parallel. Last case the lines form the sides of a triangle and an equilateral triangle can be inscribed in it.

Comment: ... (continuation of @Somos) ...as is established in (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186432/equilateral-triangle-inscribed-in-a-triangle)

Comment: I forgot another case with two parallel lines cut by a transversal line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let the three lines be $r,s,t$. Let $A\in r$.

1. Rotate $s$ by $60^\circ$ counter-clockwise around $A$ to get $s'$;
2. Define $B$ as $s'\cap t$;
3. Define $C$ as the intersection between the perpendicular bisector of $AB$ and $s$.

$ABC$ is equilateral. Can you see *why*?

[image]