# Proof that there is a point inside an acute-angled triangle so that perpendiculars dropped to the sides will form vertices of equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, problem-solving, geometric-construction

There is a character limit to the title length and the task may not be clear. So here is a little bit longer task description.

### Task description:

> You are given an acute-angled triangle $ABC$. Proof that there is a
> point $O$ inside $ABC$ so if you drop perpendiculars $OD,
> OE, OF$ to the sides:
> $$D \in AB,\; E \in BC,\; F \in AC,\; OD \bot AB,\; OE \bot
> BC,\; OF \bot AC$$
> then $DEF$ is an equilateral triangle.

### Questions I found useful:

[Inscribe an equilateral triangle inside a triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3010488/inscribe-an-equilateral-triangle-inside-a-triangle)
[Three lines are given. Find three points on these lines, one point on each line, that are vertices of an equilateral triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2541765/three-lines-are-given-find-three-points-on-these-lines-one-point-on-each-line)

### Current idea:

1. Choose $D' \in AB$
2. Inscribe an equilateral triangle $D'E'F'$ inside $ABC$ (Problem here is that sometimes $E'$ and $F'$ are outside of $BC$ and $AC$ but let's assume they are inside)
3. Draw perpendiculars to $AB$ through $D'$, to $BC$ through $E'$, to $AC$ through $F'$
4. Let's say perpendiculars through $E'$ and $F'$ intersect at $O'$
5. It seems that if we move $D'$ from $A$ to $B$ then the $O'$ will be to the $B$ side from perpenducilar through $D'$ at the beginning and to the $A$ side at the end (I can't proof this). So there will be the moment when perpendicular through $D'$ will go through $O'$.
6. At this point $O'$ seems to be $O$ we are searching for but I can't proof that $O'$ will be inside a triangle $ABC$.

**Will be pleased for any help (ideas/links to similar questions)**

**UPDATE:**
Found point $O$ in Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers (https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html):
X(15) = 1st ISODYNAMIC POINT
The pedal triangle of X(15) is equilateral.

**UPDATE 2:**
Here is how to find $O$ with straightedge and compass:
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IsodynamicPoints.html

Comment: Draw an equilateral triangle $DEF$ first, and take a point $O$ inside. Now see if you can make an arbitrary acute triangle $ABC$ by moving $O$.

Comment: @Saturday thanks. That's a nice idea - I was trying to do this before and didn't get any good results but wasn't trying a lot. Thanks for reminding me this idea

Comment: Dear friends, when you take that arbitrary point O then you will observed that , when ∆ABC become Acute then O becomes X(15) and when ∆ABC is obtuse then O become X(16) then all you have do is to prove that O will become either X(15) or X(16) with respect to ∆ABC case.

Comment: Comment of Saturday shows that the claim is correct for any triangle with angles less than 120°.